# how to do text to speech using custom keyboard in IOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I make a custom keyboard using this link 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Now I need to add functionality of text to speech . In other word when ever user press key it speech that word .can you please tell me how it is possible .is it possible in IOS 8?

Comment: Apple hasn't made voice dictation available for custom keyboards at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into following class available in ios7 onwards

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"whatever text"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

For more info please check apple's library document

[AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/index.html)

[AVSpeechUtterance](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/index.html)

Comment: Have you work on that functionality in custom keyboard?